# If I have that $X$ is a random variable with CDF $F_X(x) = P(X \leq x)$ and PDF $f_X(x)$, what is $\frac{dP(X \leq -x)}{dx}$?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory

Suppose $X$ is a random variable with CDF $F_X(x) = P(X \leq x)$ and PDF $f_X(x)$, I am trying to find

$$
\frac{dP(X \leq -x)}{dx}
$$

However, I am not familiar with differentiation of the cumulative distribution function. My intuition is that it works like:

$$
\frac{dP(X \leq -x)}{dx} = \frac{dP(X \leq -x)}{d(-x)}\frac{d(-x)}{dx} = (-1)\cdot f_X(-x) = -f_X(-x)
$$

I am not sure what role the random variable $X$ plays here, could someone tell me how I should view it? thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by the " role the random variable X plays here"?

Comment: @msm I am wondering if the derivative is both a function of $x$ and $X$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition $$F_X(x)=P(X\le x)$$ 
 The capital $X$ is there to denote the actual random variable but $F_X(x)$ is a function of $x$.

That said,$$P(X\le -x)=F_X(-x)$$ and since $$\frac{d}{dx}F_X(x)=f_X(x)$$ we can say
$$\frac{d}{dx}P(X\le -x)=\frac{d}{dx}F_X(-x)=\frac{d}{dx}(-x)f_X(-x)=-f_X(-x)$$